# Error on Customers Service while consuming (Order Service generated) message

Tags: microservices, distributed-transactions, saga, eventual-consistency

I am trying to deploy the Eventuate Tram saga [example GIT application](https://github.com/eventuate-tram/eventuate-tram-sagas-examples-customers-and-orders) with OrderService and ConsumerService.

**Order Service** is creating a new **Order** successfully and update the '**eventuate.message**' correctly.
Then **Eventuate Tram CDC Service** will send that message into **Customers Service** successfully (via the consumerService topic).
**Customers Service** is producing following exception while it consuming that message.

Thanks in advance.

```
2020-10-05 16:56:52.462  INFO 9988 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2020-10-05 16:56:52.464  INFO 9988 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2020-10-05 16:56:52.468  INFO 9988 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1601888212467 with initial instances count: 5
2020-10-05 16:56:52.470  INFO 9988 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application SAGA-CONSUMER-SERVICE with eureka with status UP
2020-10-05 16:56:52.471  INFO 9988 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1601888212471, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2020-10-05 16:56:52.474  INFO 9988 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SAGA-CONSUMER-SERVICE/ChannaX240.mshome.net:saga-consumer-service:7111: registering service...
2020-10-05 16:56:52.536  INFO 9988 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SAGA-CONSUMER-SERVICE/ChannaX240.mshome.net:saga-consumer-service:7111 - registration status: 204
2020-10-05 16:56:52.542  INFO 9988 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 7111 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-05 16:56:52.543  INFO 9988 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 7111
2020-10-05 16:56:54.451  INFO 9988 --- [           main] com.ee.ic.serviceframe.BootStrap       : Started BootStrap in 23.001 seconds (JVM running for 23.724)
2020-10-05 16:57:52.498  INFO 9988 --- [freshExecutor-0] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8761: The target server failed to respond
2020-10-05 16:57:52.499  INFO 9988 --- [freshExecutor-0] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8761
2020-10-05 16:59:32.601 DEBUG 9988 --- [mmandDispatcher] i.e.m.k.b.c.EventuateKafkaConsumer       : Got customerCommandDispatcher 1 records
2020-10-05 16:59:32.601 DEBUG 9988 --- [mmandDispatcher] i.e.m.k.b.c.EventuateKafkaConsumer       : processing record customerCommandDispatcher 0 [123, 34, 112, 97, 121, 108, 111, 97, 100, 34, 58, 34, 123, 92, 34, 111, 114, 100, 101, 114, 73, 100, 92, 34, 58, 49, 52, 44, 92, 34, 111, 114, 100, 101, 114, 84, 111, 116, 97, 108, 92, 34, 58, 123, 92, 34, 97, 109, 111, 117, 110, 116, 92, 34, 58, 52, 125, 44, 92, 34, 99, 117, 115, 116, 111, 109, 101, 114, 73, 100, 92, 34, 58, 49, 125, 34, 44, 34, 104, 101, 97, 100, 101, 114, 115, 34, 58, 123, 34, 99, 111, 109, 109, 97, 110, 100, 95, 115, 97, 103, 97, 95, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 55, 52, 102, 55, 102, 99, 99, 50, 100, 97, 45, 54, 56, 102, 55, 50, 56, 51, 97, 57, 97, 102, 54, 48, 48, 48, 48, 34, 44, 34, 68, 65, 84, 69, 34, 58, 34, 77, 111, 110, 44, 32, 53, 32, 79, 99, 116, 32, 50, 48, 50, 48, 32, 48, 56, 58, 53, 57, 58, 51, 49, 32, 71, 77, 84, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 109, 109, 97, 110, 100, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 115, 116, 101, 101, 46, 105, 99, 46, 115, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 46, 99, 117, 115, 116, 111, 109, 101, 114, 115, 46, 97, 112, 105, 46, 99, 111, 109, 109, 97, 110, 100, 115, 46, 82, 101, 115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 67, 114, 101, 100, 105, 116, 67, 111, 109, 109, 97, 110, 100, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 109, 109, 97, 110, 100, 95, 114, 101, 112, 108, 121, 95, 116, 111, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 115, 116, 101, 101, 46, 105, 99, 46, 115, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 46, 99, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 46, 115, 97, 103, 97, 46, 67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 79, 114, 100, 101, 114, 83, 97, 103, 97, 45, 114, 101, 112, 108, 121, 34, 44, 34, 68, 69, 83, 84, 73, 78, 65, 84, 73, 79, 78, 34, 58, 34, 99, 117, 115, 116, 111, 109, 101, 114, 83, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 109, 109, 97, 110, 100, 95, 115, 97, 103, 97, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 99, 111, 109, 46, 115, 116, 101, 101, 46, 105, 99, 46, 115, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 46, 99, 111, 109, 109, 111, 110, 46, 115, 97, 103, 97, 46, 67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 79, 114, 100, 101, 114, 83, 97, 103, 97, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 109, 109, 97, 110, 100, 95, 95, 100, 101, 115, 116, 105, 110, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 34, 99, 117, 115, 116, 111, 109, 101, 114, 83, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34, 44, 34, 73, 68, 34, 58, 34, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 55, 52, 102, 55, 102, 99, 99, 52, 49, 100, 45, 54, 56, 102, 55, 50, 56, 51, 97, 57, 97, 102, 54, 48, 48, 48, 48, 34, 125, 44, 34, 105, 100, 34, 58, 34, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 55, 52, 102, 55, 102, 99, 99, 52, 49, 100, 45, 54, 56, 102, 55, 50, 56, 51, 97, 57, 97, 102, 54, 48, 48, 48, 48, 34, 125]
2020-10-05 16:59:32.602 DEBUG 9988 --- [mmandDispatcher] i.e.m.k.b.c.EventuateKafkaConsumer       : EventuateKafkaAggregateSubscriptions subscriber = customerCommandDispatcher, offset = 0, key = 00000174f7fcc41d-68f7283a9af60000, value = [B@61d0191b
2020-10-05 16:59:32.608 DEBUG 9988 --- [mmandDispatcher] i.e.m.k.b.c.EventuateKafkaConsumer       : Processed customerCommandDispatcher 1 records
2020-10-05 16:59:32.608 DEBUG 9988 --- [mmandDispatcher] i.e.m.k.b.c.EventuateKafkaConsumer       : To commit customerCommandDispatcher io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.basic.consumer.OffsetTracker@15aba9f6[state={customerService-0=io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.basic.consumer.TopicPartitionOffsets@5398cd8d[unprocessed=[0],processed=[]]}]
2020-10-05 16:59:32.732 ERROR 9988 --- [pool-1-thread-1] i.e.t.c.c.DecoratedMessageHandlerFactory : Got exception customerCommandDispatcher 00000174f7fcc41d-68f7283a9af60000
2020-10-05 16:59:32.744 ERROR 9988 --- [pool-1-thread-1] i.e.t.c.c.DecoratedMessageHandlerFactory : Got exception 

java.lang.RuntimeException: No method for io.eventuate.tram.messaging.common.MessageImpl@902a931[payload={"orderId":14,"orderTotal":{"amount":4},"customerId":1},headers={command_saga_id=00000174f7fcc2da-68f7283a9af60000, DATE=Mon, 5 Oct 2020 08:59:31 GMT, command_type=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.customers.api.commands.ReserveCreditCommand, command_reply_to=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.common.saga.CreateOrderSaga-reply, DESTINATION=customerService, command_saga_type=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.common.saga.CreateOrderSaga, command__destination=customerService, ID=00000174f7fcc41d-68f7283a9af60000}]
    at io.eventuate.tram.commands.consumer.CommandDispatcher.messageHandler(CommandDispatcher.java:58) ~[eventuate-tram-commands-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.sagas.participant.SagaCommandDispatcher.messageHandler(SagaCommandDispatcher.java:42) ~[eventuate-tram-sagas-participant-0.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DecoratedMessageHandlerFactory.lambda$decorate$0(DecoratedMessageHandlerFactory.java:33) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.java:25) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.java:10) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.lambda$accept$0(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:13) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.jdbc.SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.lambda$doWithMessage$0(SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.java:52) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-jdbc-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.common.common.spring.jdbc.EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.lambda$executeInTransaction$0(EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.java:18) ~[eventuate-common-common-spring-jdbc-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.eventuate.common.common.spring.jdbc.EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.executeInTransaction(EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.java:18) ~[eventuate-common-common-spring-jdbc-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.jdbc.SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.doWithMessage(SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.java:50) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-jdbc-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:13) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:3) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator.accept(OptimisticLockingDecorator.java:20) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator.accept(OptimisticLockingDecorator.java:12) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be528231.invoke(<generated>) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11288949.accept(<generated>) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.java:24) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.java:10) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageConsumerImpl.lambda$subscribe$0(MessageConsumerImpl.java:39) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.kafka.EventuateTramKafkaMessageConsumer.lambda$subscribe$0(EventuateTramKafkaMessageConsumer.java:29) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-kafka-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.handle(MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.java:71) ~[eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.lambda$null$0(MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.java:41) ~[eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.SwimlaneDispatcher.processQueuedMessage(SwimlaneDispatcher.java:72) ~[eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_112]

2020-10-05 16:59:32.745 ERROR 9988 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .c.PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator : decoration failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: No method for io.eventuate.tram.messaging.common.MessageImpl@902a931[payload={"orderId":14,"orderTotal":{"amount":4},"customerId":1},headers={command_saga_id=00000174f7fcc2da-68f7283a9af60000, DATE=Mon, 5 Oct 2020 08:59:31 GMT, command_type=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.customers.api.commands.ReserveCreditCommand, command_reply_to=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.common.saga.CreateOrderSaga-reply, DESTINATION=customerService, command_saga_type=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.common.saga.CreateOrderSaga, command__destination=customerService, ID=00000174f7fcc41d-68f7283a9af60000}]
    at io.eventuate.tram.commands.consumer.CommandDispatcher.messageHandler(CommandDispatcher.java:58) ~[eventuate-tram-commands-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.sagas.participant.SagaCommandDispatcher.messageHandler(SagaCommandDispatcher.java:42) ~[eventuate-tram-sagas-participant-0.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DecoratedMessageHandlerFactory.lambda$decorate$0(DecoratedMessageHandlerFactory.java:33) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.java:25) [eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.java:10) [eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) [eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.lambda$accept$0(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:13) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.jdbc.SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.lambda$doWithMessage$0(SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.java:52) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-jdbc-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.common.common.spring.jdbc.EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.lambda$executeInTransaction$0(EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.java:18) ~[eventuate-common-common-spring-jdbc-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.eventuate.common.common.spring.jdbc.EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.executeInTransaction(EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.java:18) ~[eventuate-common-common-spring-jdbc-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.jdbc.SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.doWithMessage(SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.java:50) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-jdbc-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:13) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:3) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) [eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator.accept(OptimisticLockingDecorator.java:20) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator.accept(OptimisticLockingDecorator.java:12) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be528231.invoke(<generated>) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11288949.accept(<generated>) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) [eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.java:24) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.java:10) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) [eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageConsumerImpl.lambda$subscribe$0(MessageConsumerImpl.java:39) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.kafka.EventuateTramKafkaMessageConsumer.lambda$subscribe$0(EventuateTramKafkaMessageConsumer.java:29) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-kafka-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.handle(MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.java:71) ~[eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.lambda$null$0(MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.java:41) ~[eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.SwimlaneDispatcher.processQueuedMessage(SwimlaneDispatcher.java:72) ~[eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_112]

2020-10-05 16:59:32.751 ERROR 9988 --- [pool-1-thread-1] i.e.m.k.b.c.KafkaMessageProcessor        : Got exception: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: No method for io.eventuate.tram.messaging.common.MessageImpl@902a931[payload={"orderId":14,"orderTotal":{"amount":4},"customerId":1},headers={command_saga_id=00000174f7fcc2da-68f7283a9af60000, DATE=Mon, 5 Oct 2020 08:59:31 GMT, command_type=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.customers.api.commands.ReserveCreditCommand, command_reply_to=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.common.saga.CreateOrderSaga-reply, DESTINATION=customerService, command_saga_type=com.ee.ic.serviceframe.common.saga.CreateOrderSaga, command__destination=customerService, ID=00000174f7fcc41d-68f7283a9af60000}]
    at io.eventuate.tram.commands.consumer.CommandDispatcher.messageHandler(CommandDispatcher.java:58) ~[eventuate-tram-commands-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.sagas.participant.SagaCommandDispatcher.messageHandler(SagaCommandDispatcher.java:42) ~[eventuate-tram-sagas-participant-0.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DecoratedMessageHandlerFactory.lambda$decorate$0(DecoratedMessageHandlerFactory.java:33) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.java:25) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostHandlerMessageHandlerDecorator.java:10) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.lambda$accept$0(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:13) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.jdbc.SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.lambda$doWithMessage$0(SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.java:52) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-jdbc-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.common.common.spring.jdbc.EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.lambda$executeInTransaction$0(EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.java:18) ~[eventuate-common-common-spring-jdbc-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.eventuate.common.common.spring.jdbc.EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.executeInTransaction(EventuateSpringTransactionTemplate.java:18) ~[eventuate-common-common-spring-jdbc-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.jdbc.SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.doWithMessage(SqlTableBasedDuplicateMessageDetector.java:50) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-jdbc-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:13) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(DuplicateDetectingMessageHandlerDecorator.java:3) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator.accept(OptimisticLockingDecorator.java:20) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator.accept(OptimisticLockingDecorator.java:12) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be528231.invoke(<generated>) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at io.eventuate.tram.spring.optimisticlocking.OptimisticLockingDecorator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11288949.accept(<generated>) ~[eventuate-tram-spring-optimistic-locking-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.java:24) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.accept(PrePostReceiveMessageHandlerDecorator.java:10) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.lambda$buildChain$0(MessageHandlerDecoratorChainBuilder.java:38) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common.MessageConsumerImpl.lambda$subscribe$0(MessageConsumerImpl.java:39) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-common-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.tram.consumer.kafka.EventuateTramKafkaMessageConsumer.lambda$subscribe$0(EventuateTramKafkaMessageConsumer.java:29) ~[eventuate-tram-consumer-kafka-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.handle(MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.java:71) [eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.lambda$null$0(MessageConsumerKafkaImpl.java:41) [eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at io.eventuate.messaging.kafka.consumer.SwimlaneDispatcher.processQueuedMessage(SwimlaneDispatcher.java:72) ~[eventuate-messaging-kafka-consumer-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_112]

16:59:32.752 ERROR 9988 --- [pool-1-thread-1] i.e.m.kafka.consumer.SwimlaneDispatcher  : Exception handling message - terminating
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your logs it seems it is not connecting to Kafka at 8761 port.May be restarting the same will work.If you are running it from docker check if it is running or exited.